# Websockets not working on live nodejs app and nextjs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, websocket, next.js

this code is in my `nodejs` backend (`https://backend.example.com`) `server.js` file:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const server = new WebSocket.Server({
        port: 7500
    },
    () => {
        console.log('Server started on port 7500');
    }
);
```

This code is in my `nextjs` frontend chat (`http://frontend.example.com/chat`) page file:

```
    React.useEffect(() => {

        ws.current = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:7500");

        ws.current.onopen = () => {
            console.log("Connection opened");
            setConnectionOpen(true);
        };

        ws.current.onmessage = (event) => {
            const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
            setMessages((_messages) => [..._messages, data]);
        };

        return () => {
            console.log("Cleaning up...");
            ws.current.close();
        };
    }, []);
```

it works fine in `localhost` but on deployed live server, the `websocket` is not communicating, what is wrong with my code?

**EDIT:** Have updated the `useEffect()` to:

```
    React.useEffect(() => {

        ws.current = new WebSocket("wss://backend.example.com:7500");

        ws.current.onopen = () => {
            console.log("Connection opened");
            setConnectionOpen(true);
        };

        ws.current.onmessage = (event) => {
            const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
            setMessages((_messages) => [..._messages, data]);
        };

        return () => {
            console.log("Cleaning up...");
            ws.current.close();
        };
    }, []);
```

but still it does not work, If I visit the `https://backend.example.com` I get `Upgrade Required`

Answer (score 0):

If this is the code you deploy on live server, then I think the following points have to be addressed.

On the client you point to `localhost`, you should have the server name, instead.

And more important, in local you're publishing the app in `http`, while in live server it is in `https`?

In this case the WebSocket url should change the protocol from `ws` to `wss`.

**UPDATE**

Another point of attention is your server.

I don't see code that is handling the connection, according to the documentation [example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#usage-examples).

```js
import WebSocket from 'ws';

const ws = new WebSocket('ws://www.host.com/path');

// This handle the co
ws.on('open', function open() {
  ws.send('something');
});

ws.on('message', function message(data) {
  console.log('received: %s', data);
});
```

If this is not the library you're using, please update your question whit all the references to the library you're using or the documentation you're referring to to write your code.

About the port, there is nothing specific about the port, the only issue is that you can have the port blocked, on the firewall of your client or on the network gateway of your server.

But that depends on your environment, you should check if the port is usable.
A simple test is to try a small server with an html page published on the `7500` port on your server. If you can see the page the port is ok.

And more you should **not** use the same port of your server, pick another one, because the http server is reserving that port, and your WebSocket will fail attempting to bind.
But you should see an error on the server if that happened.

If you want to use your application server port, instead of starting a different server then follow this [example](https://github.com/websockets/ws#multiple-servers-sharing-a-single-https-server).

Comment: hi, I have updated the code, but websocket is still not connecting, on client side do I really need to use port `7500`? or I should use something different from the server port `7500`?